# Launch quicklook from the command line in full screen mode

Tags: quicklook

Is it possible to launch quicklook from the command line in full screen? `qlmanage` does not seem to have any option for that.

Comment: I thought I'd found an easy way to view my problematic iPhone photos (HEIC etc) on my Mac on my unused high resolution display, then I read the answer to this. I'm so deflated.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what you meant, but you could reveal the file in Finder and emulate pressing option-space:

`open -R .; osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to keystroke space using option down' -e 'tell app "Finder" to close window 1'`

Comment: Yes, that works but is really not ideal. Not only because it opens and closes a window, but also because I have that specific shortcut remapped.

Comment: This just opens a finder window for me.